# how to add toggle button in ionic

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to add toggle button with button bar (right side) as show in image![enter image description here][1]

I am able to make button bar and I added toggle button from this link
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionToggle/

but my toggle button come below the button bar .I need it should come along with button bar as show in image
here is my code

```
  <div class="" id="buttonTab" style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray">


  <div class="button-bar">

            </div>
            <div>
<ion-toggle ng-model="airplaneMode" toggle-class="toggle-calm">Show Attachment</ion-toggle>            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your question is about `CSS`, not `Angular`, so please update your title & tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to put the button (`ion-toggle` element) inside the `.button-bar` and float it right.

See it in action here, with `position: absolute;` and `right: 0;`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YvSwWgNzEioW0Lpvm04i?p=preview

Comment: can we decrease the width of button bar buttons?

Comment: There's a working plunker - the float didn't work because of the bar's right padding, so that one needs tweaking. Sure, you can decrease the width, just make sure it's set to inline-block then.

Comment: there is problem in solution ..toggle button attacted to bar button ..it is not look as I want ..please check image it is some pixel apart from bar

Comment: Use margins to position it.

Comment: see this http://plnkr.co/edit/3RQsUusKuGe3ABXleOVM?p=preview ..please check in full screen of plunker .my last button of button bar border not display and it is not using margin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82846/discussion-between-shruti-and-shomz).

Answer (score 0):

check this . http://plnkr.co/edit/MuMTo8cmNaV2p6W7mFMt?p=preview

your button-bar has width:100% and padding  . I made the width 75% and removed the padding and floated it to left  and toggle div to right

```
.button-bar {
   /* padding: 1% 18% 1% 18%;*/
    float:left;
    width:75% !important;
}
```

Comment: Ionic framework is made for building mobile Apps .  I don't think mobile screens have room to display four buttons and a toggle button floated right. Consider changing your design

Comment: I am working on tablets .it have enough space in that ..:)